# W3C widget like application package for MeeGo and Maemo

Tags: widget, w3c, meego, maemo

I've seen info on ovi that it supports widgets but can't seem to find any decent tutorial or even documentation on how would I build such an app.

I know I can just copy my HTML (and other) files and run in the browser (or at least in N9 I can), but I would like to be able to also add a shortcut (icon) on the apps screen. I thought this could be handled by a simple widget configuration file, but can't seem to find any docs for Nokia on it.

I don't mind having url bar too much, but no app icon by default would be a problem for "normal" users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found more-or less an answer for my question - at least on Nokia N9 (from 1.1) - you can use offline applications. See [information specific to Nokia](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Web/web-apps/html5-based-web-apps.html) (includes info on app icons) or [more general on MDN](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/offline-web-applications/). You can also find some [compatibility information on Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=offline).

BTW from my experience in Opera Mobile you need to use "Saved pages" function for offline apps to work (you also need to open them from saved pages, not from bookmarks).